# Laravel 9 Array Filter

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-9

I have this array cart_items and works fine when mapped for database storage as in the code.

```
$cart_items = [
    {"id":8,
    "cart_id":7,
    "product_id":4,
    "variation_id":null,
    "quantity":1,
    "price":30,
    "tax":0,
    "attrs":null,
    "gross_total":30,
    "net_total":30,
    "tax_total":0,
    "product":{
        "id":4,
        "parent_id":null,
        "category_id":1,
        "shop_id":1,
        "title":"Ladies Blazer",
        "unit":"item",
        "sale_price":30,
        "general_price":35
        }
    },
    {
    "id":9,
    "cart_id":7,
    "product_id":1,
    "variation_id":null,
    "quantity":2,
    "price":11,
    "tax":0,
    "attrs":null,
    "gross_total":22,
    "net_total":22,
    "tax_total":0,
    "product":{
        "id":1,
        "parent_id":null,
        "category_id":2,
        "shop_id":2,
        "title":"Sport Bottles",
        "unit":"item",
        "sale_price":11,
        "general_price":9
        }
    }
]
```

```
    $line_item_params = $cart_items->map(function (CartItem $item) {
        $p = [
                'product_id' => $item->product_id,
                //add filtered shop_id here        
                'variation_id' => $item->variation_id,
                'product_title' => $item->product->title,
                'quantity' => $item->quantity,
                'price' => $item->price,
                'tax' => $item->tax,
                'attrs' => $item->attrs,
            ];
        return $p;
    })->toArray();
```

I need to filter the array using Arr:where(), where the product shop_id is a specific value.

I tried using an if function but the code just looped returing true where the shop_id was present.

```
    $line_item_params = $cart_items->map(function (CartItem $item) {

        if ($item->product['shop_id'] == 1){
            $p = [
                    'product_id' => $item->product_id,
                       //add filtered shop_id here        
                       //'shop_id' => $shop->id,
                    'variation_id' => $item->variation_id,
                    'product_title' => $item->product->title,
                    'quantity' => $item->quantity,
                    'price' => $item->price,
                    'tax' => $item->tax,
                    'attrs' => $item->attrs,
                ];
        }
        return $p;
    })->toArray();
```

I need to filter the array where the product shop_id is a specific value.

Comment: Ok, so what the problem, you appear to know what you want to do and how to do it?

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: If I understand the problem, you could use to steps: 1. Filter the array by $item->product_id with the Arr::where-helper. 2. Map the resulting array like you already did with Array::map().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this solution is not desirable.  It would be too simplistic. You want to do it with Laravel 9 components. I'll show you anyway:

```
$shop_id = 1;
$result = array_filter($arr, fn($v) => $v["product"]["shop_id"] == $shop_id);
```

Complete example: https://3v4l.org/19gnD

Comment: Thanks @jspit, compared your answer to Onki Hara's and got it.. thanks